# Scroll a ListView to the top without any screen flickering

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented a ListView that has the functionality that you see in many apps, where user scrolls to bottom and it loads more, that OnScrollListener is this:

```
public class OnScrolledToEndListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener
{
    private int prevLast;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int first, int visible, int total)
    {
        int last = first + visible;
        if (last == total)
        {
            if (prevLast != last)
            {
                prevLast = last;
                onScrolledToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onScrolledToEnd()
    {

    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when a user has scrolled to the bottom of a list, and hits the refresh button in my app, I want it to start over at the top of the list, because if it stays at the bottom of the list, then the scroll listener will immediately trigger.  The best way I've found to solve this is by doing the following before executing the refresh:

```
mListView.setSelection(0);
mListView.post(
    new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mLoadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //this is basically a progressbar
            // do the refresh
        }
    }
);
```

But there is a slight flicker when the list scrolls to the top.  Any ideas on how to make it look better?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution.  Apparently setting the ListView to `View.GONE` makes it not update its layout, so I set it to `View.INVISIBLE` instead and it worked.  I didn't even have to use a Runnable.

```
mListView.setSelection(0);
mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
mLoadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```